# PHP - Fopen to cURL

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I'm adapting the code of a web based system I use, given that on my development ambient I have the fopen() function activated, but on the production ambient, I haven't this function active, for security reasons.
On the code, I have this function:

```
function PostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );
    if ($optional_headers !== null)
    {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
    {
        die("Problem reading data from " . $url . "");
    }

    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);

    // var_dump($response);

    if ($response == false)
    {
        die("Problem reading data from " . $url . "");
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I changed its to:

```
function PostRequest($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );
    if ($optional_headers !== null)
    {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }

    // Customizations for fopen() or curl()

    if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen') == true)
    {
        $params = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $data
            )
        );
        if ($optional_headers !== null)
        {
            $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
        }

        $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        if (!$fp)
        {
            die("Problem reading data from " . $url . "");
        }

        $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);

        // var_dump($response);

        if ($response == false)
        {
            die("Problem reading data from " . $url . "");
        }

        return $response;
    }
    else
    if (function_exists('curl_init'))
    {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }
    else
    {
        die("Problem reading data from " . $url . "");
    }
}
```

The problem in here, is this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /path/classes/xmwsclient.class.php on line 133 API Error: No 'request'
>   method was recieved

And from what I'm searched, the problem is because:

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params);

But I don't know how to adapt this piece of code, because the array $params is created as soon:

```
<?php

$params = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    )
);

if ($optional_headers !== null)
{
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
}
```

And when I print this array, it's what I obtain:

> Array ( [http] => Array ( [method] => POST [content] =>
>   0e0c97c0663f5db12a6ccfef0a513da3 GetSettings 1 ) )

Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Your code is impossible to read in its current state. Please add proper line breaks and indentation.

Comment: Ident your code properly pleaseà

Comment: @rafael fixed your formatting via http://phpbeautifier.com/ , please post code with formatting

Comment: I tried, but when I sent to post, the system returns error with the code. :S

Comment: Thanks skrrgwasme! I'll try this when I open the next topic or insert the next code! :)

Comment: Thanks Erik! I'll use this site on the future to post codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` does not take an `array[]`, which is what you're passing here.

```
$params = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    )
);
```

Also, this is not the correct use of it. This would be your `$optional_headers`, converted to a `string[]` if necessary. To set these parameters, you'd use `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

`$data` will need to be either a `string[]` containing your raw data, or a `string` containing the url-encoded data. Passing an array will set `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` while a string will set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information.

Comment: @Rafael If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted, with the checkmark right under the vote buttons.